CheckBox in DataGrid does not trigger property change in the binding source
I have a DataGrid that displays a list of items
there is a check box in each row that should change a Boolean field from the corresponding data class

I expect the field value to change and the OnPropertyChanged to trigger

as the app initializes, the setter is triggered upon list initialization

when I click on any checkbox, the setter is never triggered


here is the Control xaml:
<DataGrid x:Name="ModificationsGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Value}"  >
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Enabled, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

The corresponding Data class
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyNameSpace.refactor
{
    // Refactor operation data
    public class RefactorOperation : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public RefactorOperation(int startLine, int startChar, int endLine, int endChar, string[] content, bool enabled)
        {
            StartLine = startLine;
            StartCharacter = startChar;
            EndLine = endLine;
            EndCharacter = endChar;
            Content = content;
            Enabled = enabled;
        }

        public int StartLine { get; set; }
        public int StartCharacter { get; set; }
        public int EndLine { get; set; }
        public int EndCharacter { get; set; }
        public string[] Content { get; set; }

        private bool _enabled; // field related to below property
        public bool Enabled
        {
            get { return _enabled; }
            set
            {   
                // should trigger on chekcbox interactions
                _enabled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Enabled)); 
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

Am I missing something ?
thanks for your help

Use a tool like Snoop (you might be able to use the tools in VS 2022 for this) and see what the DataContext is for the checkbox. IOW, don't assume it's what you think it is. Check for XAML binding warnings, also.

the datacontext is the right one, since the checkbox reflects the initial state of the enabled field

Add
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

to your CheckBox IsChecked data binding. The default is LostFocus, which requires you to switch focus to a different control before the bound property value is updated.

UpdateSourceTrigger is not recognized

<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding xxx, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/> works fine for me.

UpdateSourceTrigger is not even in the popup list
